# How to omit the constructor parameter with a default value when calling Kotlin in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

My kotlin file:

```
class Chat(var name: String, var age: Int? = 18)
```

My java file only can do this:

```
new Chat("John",18);
```

But could i just write this ?

```
new Chat("John");
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From [Kotlin document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#overloads-generation):

> Normally, if you write a Kotlin method with default parameter values, it will be visible in Java only as a full signature, with all parameters present. If you wish to expose multiple overloads to Java callers, you can use the @JvmOverloads annotation.

So, if you want to initialize `Chat` with `name` only in Java, you have to add `@JvmOverloads` annotation to the constructor.

```
class Chat @JvmOverloads constructor(var name: String, var age: Int? = 18)
```

It will generate additional overload for each parameter with a default value.

```
public Chat(String name) {}
public Chat(String name, Integer age) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but I want to point out one thing - if all of the constructor arguments are optional, [then the constructor with no arguments will be generated](https://kt.academy/article/ak-java-interop-3#:%7E:text=%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D-,JvmOverloads,-Another%20inconsistency%20between), and therefore you do not need `@JvmOverloads`.

For instance, if you have in kotlin:

```
class MyEntity(var name: String = "alex", var age: Int = 18)
```

then in java bytecode you will have an all args constructor, as well as no-args constructor, therefore you will be able to do in Java both of these:

```
new MyEntity(); // no args
new MyEntity("custom name", 24); // all args
```

without any extra annotation